# por que muestra algunas cosas con www, y otras no?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, servidor

logre instalar un certificado SSL en mi dominio, pero desde que uso https todo a sido un lio! me saltan errores por todos lados, ya con paciencia, logre solucionar dichos errores, menos uno, que me tiene tilteado.

la pagina es https://saltapersonalizados.com/

en la pagina puede mostrar o no una imagen o archivo js segun la direccion, ej.

https://saltapersonalizados.com/i/reds.png asi no la muestra, pero las demas si las muestra.

https://www.saltapersonalizados.com/i/reds.png y asi si la muestra, pero las demas con www no muestra.

en resumen, si no utilizo www, solo me salen 2 errores, si utilizo www, me salen mas errores, hasta archivos js, todos con el error 522, se de que trata el error 522, pero no comprendo como se inicia dicho error. no tiene sentido, al menos para mi, disculpen la ignorancia.

me dan orientación para lograr solucionar este problema

Comment: tengo el certificado como puedes ver en esta imagen: http://subirimagen.me/uploads/20190120102910.png , funciona tanto con el dominio principal, y sub dominios(por ende www), el problema yace que no funcionan todas las direcciones, solo fallan 1 o 2 sin www, y con www fallan como 5, pero no entiendo cual es el error, he tratado de buscar en stackoverflow english, y en otros foros pero a nadie le a pasado lo mismo, ni 1 ejemplo similar a este, y me parece muy raro